# Why the convergence of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}B_{t_{i}}(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$ depend on the partition pointwise but not in $L^2$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Let $(B_t)$ a Brownian motion. Let $0=t_0<t_1<...<t_n=T$ a partition on $[0,T]$. I know that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}B_{t_{i}}(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$$
doesn't depend on the partition in $L^2$, but it does depend on the partition pointwise. I don't understand how to prove that pointwise it depend on the partition. How can I find two sequences of partition $0=t_0^{(n)}<t_1^{(n)}<...<t_{m_n}^{(n)}=T$ and $0=s_0^{(n)}<s_1^{(n)}<...<s_{p_n}^{(n)}=T$ such that $$\sum_{k=0}^{m_n-1}B_{t_i^{(n)}}(B_{t_{i+1}^{(n)}}-B_{t_i^{(n)}})\quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{k=0}^{p_n-1}B_{s_i^{(n)}}(B_{s_{i+1}^{(n)}}-B_{s_i^{(n)}}),$$
converges a.s., but the limit are different ?

Comment: You might want to clarify whether you allow the partitions to depend on $\omega$ or not...

Comment: @saz: Thanks for your comment. I think it's a good question, but I don't really see what would change... what do you think ? in the definition, the partition doesn't depend on $\omega $, does it ?

Comment: Not sure which definition you are refering to; it's not clear from your question. If you mean the definition of Itô's integral, then, yes, the partitions do not depend on $\omega$. What it changes? Well, for instance for the quadratic variation of Brownian motion it is known that it converges in $L^2$ but it can be shown that with probability $1$ there exists a sequence of nested partitions (with mesh size going to zero) such that the variation sums diverge. This indicates that some bad things happen if we allow for $\omega$-dependent partitions.

Comment: Well, my definition is for all partition $0\leq t_1^{(n)}<t_1^{(n)}<...<t_{m_n}^{(n)}=T$ s.t. $\Delta t_{i}^{(n)}\to 0$, we have $\sum_{k=0}^{m_n-1}f(t_i^{(n)},X_{t_i^{(n)}})(B_{t_{i+1}^{(n)}}-B_{t_{i}^{(n)}})$ converges in $L^2$ to $\int_0^T f(t,X_t)dB_t$. Does it make sense for you ?

Comment: @saz: I know you are french, so here is the definition I use (on french [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int%C3%A9grale_d%27It%C5%8D) )

Comment: Living in France doesn't imply being french (... in fact, I'm not french). Anyway, it is now clear to me that you consider deterministic partitions.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible ! If both of your sum converges a.s., then they will have the same limit. Indeed, they have the same limit in $L^2$. Now, a basic result of measure theory says that if $f_n(x)\to g(x)$ pointwise and $f_n(x)\to h(x)$ in $L^2$, then $g(x)=h(x)$ a.e.